# SQL Server Bulk Insert Error 7301 "IID_IColumnsInfo"

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, bulkinsert

I'm trying to insert through a CSV file, which by the way will be executed every day through a procedure, but it gives the same error.

> Msg 7301, Level 16, State 2, Line 16
>   Cannot obtain the required interface ("IID_IColumnsInfo") from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)".

The table I'm trying to import I put all the fields as `nvarchar` and all of them with at least 500 characters, because I was thinking that this was the problem.

This CSV file I am exporting through PowerShell as follows:

```bsh
Export-Csv -Path $DirPath -Delimiter ';' -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```

The file has 40 columns and 685 rows, I already tried to save the CSV file with ',' delimiter and ';' delimiter, but both have the same error.

I tried to do the Bulk Insert in several ways as below, but without success.

```sql
BULK INSERT DEV_DS_SANTOGRAU..GB_TBIMP_FOTOS_CSV
FROM 'C:\Users\userbi\Desktop\Projetos-Santo-Grau\Projeto1-RelatoriodeEstoque\TBIMP_FOTOS_CSV.csv'
WITH (FORMAT = 'CSV', 
      --MAXERRORS = 0,
      --CODEPAGE = '65001',
      CODEPAGE = 'ACP',
      --FIELDQUOTE = '"', 
      FIELDTERMINATOR ='";"', 
      --ROWTERMINATOR ='"\n"',
      ROWTERMINATOR = '\r\n',
      --ROWTERMINATOR = "0x0a"
      FIRSTROW = 2,
      ERRORFILE = 'C:\Users\userbi\Desktop\Projetos-Santo-Grau\Projeto1-RelatoriodeEstoque\TBIMP_FOTOS_CSV_ERROS.csv');
```

Once he exported a CSV and TXT file with errors, using the code above, the data was like this (but not in the original file):

[image]

What should I do?

I would not like it, but if it is possible to ignore these records but the insert is completed, it would be less worse.

Information:

- SQL Server 2019 (v15.0.18330.0)
- SQL Server Management Objects (SMO) v16.100.37971.0
- Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio v18.5

Comment: File paths for `BULK INSERT` are relative to SQL Server's point of view. Does `C:\Users\userbi\Desktop\Projetos-Santo-Grau\Projeto1-RelatoriodeEstoque\TBIMP_FOTOS_CSV.csv` exist as a file on the SQL Server's C: drive (and SQL Server has file system permissions to access it), or is it a file on your local computer's C: drive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's usually easier to `BULK INSERT` data with a format file. Use the bcp.exe utility to create a format file with a command such as the following:

```
bcp.exe DEV_DS_SANTOGRAU..GB_TBIMP_FOTOS_CSV format nul -c -t; -f C:\Temp\TBIMP_FOTOS_CSV.fmt -S(local) -T
```

Where:

- `DEV_DS_SANTOGRAU..GB_TBIMP_FOTOS_CSV` is the Database.Schema.Table we're interacting with.
- `format` specifies format file creation mode.
- `nul` specifies the input/output data file, which in this case means "don't write any data".
- `-c` specifies character mode, as opposed to native (binary) mode.
- `-t;` specifies to use `;` as the field separator character.
- `-f C:\Temp\TBIMP_FOTOS_CSV.fmt` specifies the path to write the format file to, relative to your local computer.
- `-S(local)` is the SQL Server to connect to, `(local)` in my case.
- `-T` means Trusted Authentication (Windows authentication), use `-uUsername` and `-pPassword` if you have SQL Login authentication instead.

This creates a format file something like the following (yours will have more and different columns):

```
14.0
2
1       SQLCHAR             0       510     ";"      1     Filename                 SQL_Latin1_General_Pref_CP1_CI_AS
2       SQLCHAR             0       510     "\r\n"   2     Resolution               SQL_Latin1_General_Pref_CP1_CI_AS
```

Now, in SSMS, you should be able to run something like the following to import your data file (adjust file paths relative to your SQL Server as appropriate):

```sql
BULK INSERT DEV_DS_SANTOGRAU..GB_TBIMP_FOTOS_CSV
FROM 'C:\Temp\TBIMP_FOTOS_CSV.csv'
WITH (
    CODEPAGE = '65001',
    DATAFILETYPE = 'char',
    FORMAT = 'CSV', 
    FORMATFILE = 'C:\Temp\TBIMP_FOTOS_CSV.fmt'
);
```

-- edit --

**On SQL Server and international character support.**

SQL Server and UTF-8 has had a bit of a checkered history, only gaining partial support with SQL Server 2016 and really only supporting UTF-8 code pages with SQL Server 2019. Importing and exporting files with international characters is still best handled using UTF-16 encoded files. Adjustments to the workflow are as follows...

In PowerShell, use the `Unicode` encoding instead of `UTF8`:

```
Export-Csv -Path $DirPath -Delimiter ';' -NoTypeInformation -Encoding Unicode
```

When generating the BCP format file, use the `-w` switch (for widechar) instead of `-c` (for char):

```
bcp.exe DEV_DS_SANTOGRAU..GB_TBIMP_FOTOS_CSV format nul -w -t; -f C:\Temp\TBIMP_FOTOS_CSV-widechar.fmt -S(local) -T
```

This causes the `SQLCHAR` columns to be written out as `SQLNCHAR`, aka. national character support:

```
14.0
2
1       SQLNCHAR            0       510     ";\0"        1     Filename                 SQL_Latin1_General_Pref_CP1_CI_AS
2       SQLNCHAR            0       510     "\r\0\n\0"   2     Resolution               SQL_Latin1_General_Pref_CP1_CI_AS
```

When using `BULK INSERT` specify `DATAFILETYPE = 'widechar'` instead of `DATAFILETYPE = 'char'` and specifying a codepage, e.g.:

```sql
BULK INSERT GB_TBIMP_FOTOS_CSV
FROM 'C:\Temp\TBIMP_FOTOS_CSV.csv'
WITH (
    DATAFILETYPE = 'widechar',
    FORMATFILE = 'C:\Temp\TBIMP_FOTOS_CSV-widechar.fmt'
);
```

Comment: It worked!!! What does that file .fmt do? Why do I have to use bcp.exe on CMD? Should I always use when I have to `BULK INSERT`?

Comment: According to the [bcp.exe documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql) format files can (should) be used when the number of columns in the table differs from the number of columns in the data file, or they're in a different order, or you have multiple delimiters. In practice I've found their usage just improves reliability overall, even when you have a simple data file that exactly matches the target table.

Comment: Some characters was load with some special characters with them, should I use some exception to correct them? Some columns has "â€Ž" before the data.

Comment: Try adding `FIELDQUOTE = '"'` to the bulk insert's `WITH` options list.

Comment: I really thanks to you to help me out and to edit the question, it worked! Now all the data have double quotes between them. Sorry to keep asking it to you, but do you know how?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215851/discussion-between-guilherme-matheus-and-alwayslearning).

Comment: I've sent you the link from my OneDrive with the file on chat, if you can help me with this please.

Comment: I got it! I removed the double quotes through PowerShell itself, it was easier. Dealing with importing through SQL Server was not practical. Powershell code: `$file = "C:\Users\userbi\Desktop\Projetos-Santo-Grau\Projeto1-RelatoriodeEstoque\TBIMP_FOTOS_CSV.csv"
(Get-Content $file) | Foreach-Object {$_ -replace '"', ''}|Out-File $file`